# Trying to understand gravitational force equation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, differentiation, calculus

[image]

I don't understand the red underlined equations but I understand gravitational force equation in simpler form. Can anyone please explain the equations?

**Source**
An Introduction to Celestial Mechanics by sir Richard Fitzpatrick

Comment: (2.7) is just the generalization of (2.6): a derivative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation is gravitational acceleration which is related with the gravitational force $F$  by $\vec{F}=m\vec{g}$ or in different writing $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{g}$. So equation (2.3) is just the gravitational force divided by the test mass $m$ in general coordinates. If the origin of the coordinate system is placed in the center of the mass of the field generating mass $m'$ which is equivalent with putting $\mathbf{r}'=0$  (2.3) adopts the form of the gravitational force equation:

$$\frac{\mathbf{F}}{m} = \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r}) = -G\frac{m'}{|\mathbf{r}|^3 }\mathbf{r}$$

In its simplest form only the absolute value of the force vector $\mathbf{F}$ is considered:

$$\frac{F}{m} \equiv  \frac{|\mathbf{F}|}{m} = G\frac{m'}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}|\mathbf{r}| = G\frac{m'}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}$$

or

$$F = G\frac{mm'}{X^2}$$

where $X$ denotes the length of the distance vector $\mathbf{r}$ which is $|\mathbf{r}|$ (its length). I used the uppercase letter $X$ to distinguish it from $x$.

It is the vector from the field generating mass $m'$ to the test mass $m$ (if the $m'$ is at the origin of the coordinate system, d.h. $\mathbf{r}'=0$. If the origin of the coordinate system is not at the center of mass $m'$, then the distance vector between the $m$ and $m'$ is $\mathbf{r-r'}$.

The rest of the post is just calculus in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you don't understand these steps, you should envisage to study vector algebra and vector analysis.
I give you a bit taste of it:

$$\mathbf{r} = \left(\begin{array}{c} x\\ y\\ z\\\end{array} \right)$$.

$$\mathbf{r'} = \left(\begin{array}{c} x'\\ y'\\ z'\\\end{array} \right)$$.

$$\mathbf{r'-r} = \left(\begin{array}{c} x'-x\\ y'-y\\ z'-z \\\end{array}\right)$$.

$$\mathbf{g} = \left(\begin{array}{c} g_x\\ g_y\\ g_z\\\end{array} \right)$$.

$$|\mathbf{r}| = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}$$

$$|\mathbf{r'-r}| = \sqrt{(x'-x)^2 +(y'-y)^2 +(z'-z)^2}$$

The last 2 equations is just Pythagoras in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I won't go further, it can be all found in standard textbooks on classical mechanics and on vector algebra & analysis. There you also find a definition of the gradient $\nabla$.

Answer (score 0):

R = position vector you are evaluating the field at

R' is the position vector of the mass

|R-R'| by definition is therefore the distance from the mass to the point you evaluate the field at

One of These denominator term can be factored and can be combined with r-r' to become $-\hat r$ which is the radial unit vector. This is how how the scalar force version is defined to act in the direction of.

P.s they used r'-r, I have no idea why, but this reduces to the same thing  with a minus, but using r-r' instead.